# How to control fragments using view pager and action bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am now having an activity containing fragments
[1] , [2] , [3] , [4] 
When start the application [1] and [2] run at a time.
when swipe to [2] run [3] and swipe to [3] run [4]. 
Anyone help for this problem. 
I want functionality [1] in [1], [2] in [2], and [3] in [3], [4] in [4] on tab swipe.

**below my code**
  **fragment [1]:**

```
 @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meaningview, container, false);

            word = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.word);     
            data = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web);

        if(first == 1)
        {
            try {
                dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(getActivity());
                dbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            first++;

        }
        find.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "DefaultLocale" })
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                url2 = word.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

                urlword = url2;
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                if(url2.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Word is missing! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    try{

                        urdu = dbHelper.getDetail(word.getText().toString());
                        urdu_meaning.setText(urdu.Meaning.toString());
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        urdu_meaning.setText("Urdu word not found");
                    }

                    if (mWifi.isConnected())
                    {
                        data.loadUrl(url1 + url2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

**fragment [2]**

```
 @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, container, false);
     imageView = (ImageView)  view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
     imageURL1 = imageURL + MeaningFragment.urlword + ".jpg";
             // Execute the task
     GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
     task.execute(imageURL1);
     return view;
      }
```

**Fragment [3]**

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio, container, false);

    audioURL2 = MeaningFragment.urlword + ".mp3";
                try{
                    if (isPlayed) { // if media player had played, this function is called
                        start();
                    }else {

                        try {
                            //pDialog.show();
                            mPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
                            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                            mPlayer.setDataSource(audioURL+audioURL2);
                            ac = new MediaController(getActivity());

                            ac.setAnchorView(view.findViewById(R.id.reference));
                            ac.setMediaPlayer(AudioFragment.this);
                            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(AudioFragment.this);
                            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(AudioFragment.this);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Audio URL Not Found! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        try {
                            mPlayer.prepare();
                            mPlayer.start();

                        } 
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //urdu_meaning.setText("Audio Not Found");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Audio not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }           

                    }
                }
```

**and Fragment [4] on same method**

Comment: For more understanding share apk file https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp3dhw4vthp9ecf/joltadictionary.apk?dl=0

Comment: How you are adding fragments in ViewPager?

Comment: fragments add in MainActivity and vIEWPAGEADAPTER CALSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `FragmentPagerAdapter` works is that it loads the `Fragment` *ahead* of the one you have scrolled to.  So when you start the application, fragment 1 loads and displays, fragment 2 is loaded and ready for display.  Then when you swipe, the pre-loaded fragment 2 is displayed and fragment 3 is loaded.

So if you want code to execute when the fragment is displayed in the view pager, you *cannot* put this logic in `onCreateView()`.

If you want logic to be executed when the fragment is displayed, you need to create a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and call `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` for the view pager with your listener.  In your `OnPageChangeListener`, you implement the method `onPageSelected`.  That will tell you when the fragment has displayed by a swipe.  The parameter to `onPageSelected` is the index of the fragment that was displayed, so you can tell which fragment is now visible.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    public void onPageSelected(int page) {

        switch (page) {
        case 0:
            // code for first page displayed
            break;
        case 1:
            // code for second page displayed
            break;
        case 2:
            // code for third page displayed
            break;
        case 3:
            // code for fourth page displayed
            break;
        }
    }

    // you also have to create empty impls for the other two methods
    .
    .
    .

});
```

Just a note:  If I remember correctly from when I used this, `onPageSelected` is only called on a swipe, so it might not be called the very first time your view pager is displayed. For that event, you might have to call something from the method that creates/displays your view pager.

Comment: I have Main activity for setOnPageChangeListener and another activity (ViewpageAdapter) for getItem.... as below

Answer (score 1):

I have Main activity for setOnPageChangeListener and another activity (ViewpageAdapter) for getItem.... as below

**ViewpagerAdpater**

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

        // Open FragmentTab1.java
    case 0:
        MeaningFragment meaningtab = new MeaningFragment();

        return meaningtab;
        // Open FragmentTab2.java
    case 1:
        ImageFragment imagetab = new ImageFragment();
        return imagetab;

    case 2:

        AudioFragment audiotab= new AudioFragment();
        return audiotab;

    case 3:
        VideoFragment videotab = new VideoFragment();
        return videotab;

    }
    return null;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
// Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabtitles) {

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                MainActivity.position = position;
                Log.i("Position", "Meaning =" + position);
                Log.i("Main Position", "Meaning =" + MainActivity.position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

}



@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

still in problem. i set log for position for every fragment when I swipe tabs then in onpagelistner show accurate position of every tab but in [1] and [2] show position 0 and [3] in position 1 and [4] in position 2.